# Receiving "Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size." error in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I'm looking to calculate multiple criteria from a different sheet. I tried as a COUNTIFS as well and I keep getting the "Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size." error:

=SUMIFS(Opps!A2:A6, "<>", Opps!K:K, "John Smith", "true")

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a screen shot to explain the answer that you want to derive at so that the question is much more clear.

Comment: `Opps!A2:A6` and `Opps!K:K` are not the same size.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

The `SUMIFS` formula needs two ranges that are the same size. See the examples from the link above:

```
SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, ">20")

SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, ">20", C1:C10, "<30")

SUMIFS(C1:C100, E1:E100, "Yes")
```

Note that all the ranges are exactly the same size.

In your example, the first range is and array of  4 x 1, and the criterion range is an array of inf(or however many rows you have) x 1. Since they are not the same, `SUMIFS` doesn't know how to match up the rows to the criterion.